# How to disconnect connection kafka using php-rdkafka

Tags: php, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using library for store kafka from php [php-rdkafka](https://github.com/Superbalist/php-pubsub-kafka)

My sample code is

```
$producer = new \RdKafka\Producer();
$producer->addBrokers('localhost:9092');
$topic = $producer->newTopic("my-topic");
$topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, $data_to_send);
```

When requesting a lot, this code will create a connection to a producer. I think the solution is to disconnect every time a produce message is finished. Thus, I will use one connection for one time produce and disconnect `Kafka` after that.

However, my question is how to implement this? I did not find in the `php-rdkafka` documentation how to disconnect `Kafka`.

Comment: Did you get the solution ?